# Developing trading strategy using Pandas and Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, quantitative-finance, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to identify a bullish point, based upon the following formula:

```
Bullish  Bar  =  Today’s  Low  <  Lowest  (Low  ,  13  Days)  AND  Today’s  Close  >  (((Todays  High  –  Todays  Low)  /  2)  +  Today  Low)
```

Additionally, I want to calculate the average 2 day returns of a stock for a given time period ( say, 2010 to 2017 ). For example:

```
( Close ( Day 2 ) - Open ( Day 1 ) )/ Open ( Day1 )
```

I am using Pandas to source the data. This is how the data frame looks like:

```
              Date   Close      High       Low    Open     Volume
Symbol                                                           
SPY     2010-01-01  111.44  112.8000  111.3900  112.77          0
SPY     2010-01-04  113.33  113.3900  111.5100  112.37  118944600
SPY     2010-01-05  113.63  113.6800  112.8500  113.26  111579900
```

My objective is to create a separate column where, along side the date, the bullish point is indicated, so that I can plot it with a green arrow.

Currently, I am converting everything to lists, and am using the indices of the lists to calculate the returns; however, it is pretty tedious.

Is there a way to get this done in a simpler way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataframe is called ***df***, and you want your result to be in a new column ***Return***, you can use the following code to calculate the return:

```
df['Return'] = (df.Close.shift(2) - df.Open.shift(1)) / df.Open.shift(1)
```

To calculate the bullish signal, you can use the following method:

```
    df['bullishSignal'] = (df.Low < df.Low.shift(1).rolling(13).min()) & 
                              (df.Close > ((df.High - df.Low) / 2 + df.Low))
```

Comment: This was really helpful.

Comment: Can you also explain how I can locate a date where the bullish signal is 'True'? I need this to calculate 2 day returns from that date. I did the following, but it returned that element-wise comparison failed. df[ 'bullishSignal' ].where( df[ 'bullishSignal'] == 'True' )

Comment: Glad it helps you. df[df.bullishSignal].Date will get you all the dates when the signal occurs.

Comment: That also worked! As a final question, how can I use data from the date onwards. For example, if a bullish signal occurred on 01-27-2010 (Day  ), how can I calculate: ( Close( Day 2 ) - Open( Day 1 ) ) / Open( Day 1). Presently, I am attempting to identify the index of the Date where the bullish signal occurred but because there are so many dates, I am unaware which method I can use. Thanks.

Comment: I you want to get your data from a specific date, let say the 2010-01-27, you can do the following: df.loc[df.Date >= '2010-01-27']. Just be sure that the column Date has the right type (i.e. datetime), if not just do df.Date = pd.to_date_time(df.Date).